# How can I get a list of locales in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, linux, locales

I want to change number and currency format using something like:

```sql
SET lc_numeric='en_AU.UTF-8'
SET lc_money='en_AU.UTF-8'
```

I tried a number of formats for, say, Dutch, but nothing works. It appears that I don’t have that locale on my operating system.

Ho can I get a list of available locales in PostgreSQL? There’s nothing I can find online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres uses locales provided by the underlying OS. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html)

> PostgreSQL uses the standard ISO C and POSIX locale facilities provided by the server operating system.

To see all available locales, fire up a shell and run:

```
locale -a
```

Of course, you can install more ...

The manual again:

> What locales are available on your system under what names depends on
> what was provided by the operating system vendor and what was
> installed. On most Unix systems, the command `locale -a` will provide a
> list of available locales. Windows uses more verbose locale names,
> such as `German_Germany` or `Swedish_Sweden.1252`, but the principles
> are the same.

Traditionally, `libc` has been the ["locale provider"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html#LOCALE-PROVIDERS). Since version 10 Postgres also supports **[ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode)** locales. For limited purposes at first, and Postgres needed to be built with the `--with-icu` flag to support it.
Since Postgres 15 you can use ICU collations per database.
And Postgres 16 (currently beta) has ICU support per default. There is a chapter on [ICU Locales](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/locale.html#ICU-LOCALES) in the manual since Postgres 16, accordingly.

Related blog posts by Peter Eisentraut (core developer responsible for much of this):

- https://peter.eisentraut.org/blog/2022/09/26/icu-features-in-postgresql-15
- https://peter.eisentraut.org/blog/2023/05/16/overview-of-icu-collation-settings

Comment: Ah, that’s what I thought. I though there might be a way from with PostgreSQL without touching the OS. In particular I wondered whether there was a way of adding more locales without touching the OS.

Comment: Well, there is a way to add locales. ICU locales. (Still depends on the underlying OS, though.) That only became a thing with Postgres 15, and much more with the upcoming Postgres 16. I added a bit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I’m a bit disappointed that PostgreSQL doesn’t have more intuitive locale support, but it’s on the way, I guess.

Comment: You can list the predefined collations from `pg_collations`, that might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL uses locales from either the C library or the ICU library. If you want to use C library locales, as your question suggests, you can look at

```
SELECT collname FROM pg_collation WHERE collprovider = 'c';
```

for the available collations. If the one you are looking for is missing, you'll have to create it on the operating system:

- for Redhat-based Linux distributions, install the `glibc-all-langpacks` package
- for Debian-based Linux distributions, generate the locale with

  ```bash
  locale-gen en_AU.utf8
  ```

Once you have the locale on the operating system, restart the PostgreSQL server and import the new locales into the system catalog with

```
SELECT pg_import_system_collations('pg_catalog');
```

I recommend using ICU collations, particularly from v15 on, where you can use ICU as default locale provider.